# c# mvc getting complex urls in webpage

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

when I build a table with url's in it with stringbuilder and publish it in the frontend with the ViewBag all backslashes get replaced with double quotes ?!
In the cshtm page I do:

```
@html.Raw(@viewBag.Calendar)
```

where calendar is the string which contains the table.  Original:

```
<a href='#' onclick='ShowIframe('https://public.vaptex.nl/OnlineBooking/Search/SearchSimple.aspx?relation=2EFAlKuoQrU%3d&languageid=1&objectid=ukpcLGR14nk%3d&bentityid=5&startdate=01062018&numperiod=1')'>02</a></td>
```

result in webpage

```
<a href="#" onclick="ShowIframe(" https:="" public.vaptex.nl="" onlinebooking="" search="" searchsimple.aspx?relation="2EFAlKuoQrU%3d&amp;languageid=1&amp;objectid=ukpcLGR14nk%3d&amp;bentityid=5&amp;startdate=01062018&amp;numperiod=1')'">02</a>
```

Comment: Could you not make use of a view model and `@Action.Url()` to build these urls?

Answer (score 0):

Your original string seems to have incorrect escape sequence. Try passing value in ShowIframe() with double quote(") instead of single quote(').

```
<a href='#' onclick='ShowIframe("https://public.vaptex.nl/OnlineBooking/Search/SearchSimple.aspx?relation=2EFAlKuoQrU%3d&languageid=1&objectid=ukpcLGR14nk%3d&bentityid=5&startdate=01062018&numperiod=1")'>02</a></td>
```